# Sealer for wooden ornaments?

Tags: painting, paint, wood, varnish, sealer

I have spray-painted a lightly sanded wooden ornament using Aerosal, but have noticed that the wood has lost colour in some areas after  and general handling once fully dryed. Wanted to know if there was a recommended sealer to use after i have spray painted the surface or varnish?

Comment: What kind of spray paint did you use? Was the wood treated beforehand (sanded, grounded, &c.)? Do you know *how* it lost colour? Was it due to abrasion, because it was exposed to sunlight, or something else?